# Angular $http get call very slow on IE 11

Tags: angularjs, performance, http, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have been trying to understand the performance problems on IE 11. This is specifically when I do $http.get('rest/restendpoint') . This is inside a function in angular factory and that is being called from 4-5 controllers at a time. I see in the network tab that each of the call takes 5-9 seconds.

My factory method has only $http.get call and nothing else, the controllers are doing heavy duty of processing the response, I am not experiencing problems with the processing but getting to load the json data from rest end point itself takes 6-9 seconds per api call and eventually the page load takes longer time on IE. Although performance is fine on chrome browser.

Comment: you are trying to render 1k/2k records using ng-repeat?